# Como pegar um valor de uma célula com mouseover em jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

Preciso pegar o valor de uma célula específica e move-la para uma outra *tag* HTML com `mouseover`.

Já tentei:

```
gridComplete: function () {
 $('.jqgrow').mouseover(function(e) {
  var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
 });
},
```

mas consigo só o `id` da linha e não o valor da célula que quero.

Tentei também:

```
$("#jqItensped").mouseover(function(){
 var wGrid    = $('#jqItensped');
 var selRowId = wGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
 var jqObs1   = wGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', selRowId, 'observacao1');
 $("#Witemped_Obs1").val(jqObs1);
});
```

Essa função funciona perfeitamente com `$("#jqItensped").click(function(){`, mas com `mouseover` não.

O que preciso é bastante simples. O valor está vindo do AJAX, mas não quero mostrar ele na jqGrid e sim em outra *tag* do HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Para quem possa interessar, já consegui a solução:

```all
$("#jqItensped").mouseover(function(e){
        var tr    = jQuery(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
        var wGrid = $('#jqItensped');
        var rowId = tr.attr('id');
        if (rowId) {
            var jqObs1 = wGrid.jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'observacao1');
            $("#Witemped_Obs1").val(jqObs1);
        }
});
```

Funciona com coluna *hidden* também.